# Json responses are braking/partially returned - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, json, nginx, laravel-5, envoyer.io

I have JSON data. if I `dd()` the response I can see the complete json, but if I return it as a JSON response the json is braking/partially returned/truncated and also it's not a valid json. [image: Screenshot - end of JSON response].Below is the code I am using

```
public function getLocations($json = true)
{
    $locations = [
        'countries'     => $this->mobileAppController->getCountries(),
        'states'        => $this->mobileAppController->getStates(),
        'cities'        => $this->mobileAppController->getCities(),
        'regions'       => $this->mobileAppController->getRegions()
    ];
    //dd(response()->json($locations));
    return $json ? response()->json($locations) : $locations;
}
```

> I have a homestead installation. and a staging environment. in
>   local/homestead everything works fine. the response is completely
>   returned. the staging is an envoyer server. There the response is
>   truncated/braking/partially returned. what might be the problem.?

Comment: If this is a screenshot from browser inspector, sometimes it shows part of JSON if the JSON was huge, So I suggest to check the JSON response from Postman

Comment: I checked using both postman and ARC also, and I was getting the same response. but to my surprise sometimes it completely displays the full response. will it be some problem with server?

Comment: Actually, I never experienced something like this.  Did you try to decode the JSON from javascript or something? That way you can ensure it returns a part of the response or not